# Why does Mussolini refer to war as female?

Tags: symbolism, wording-choice, italian-language, my-autobiography-mussolini, benito-mussolini

In the beginning of [Chapter Three](https://archive.org/details/MyAutobiographyBenitoMussolini/My%20Autobiography%20-%20Benito%20Mussolini/page/n51/mode/2up) of his autobiography, [Benito Mussolini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benito_Mussolini) writes the following:

> War had come — war — that female of dreads and fascinations.

What is supposed to be conveyed by calling war a "**female** of dreads and fascinations"? Is it meant to metaphorically/symbolically evoke some perceived aspect of femininity? If so, what?

A quick Google search for the phrase found no other uses besides Mussolini's autobiography, so it doesn't seem to be a common expression.

Comment: In Italian, *war* is *la guerra* — feminine. If Italians personify *war*, as Mussolini is doing, she is going to be a femaie (unless they use a synonym, like *il conflitto*, for it).

Comment: @PeterShor Isn't there a difference between using a gendered pronoun and actually calling something female? For instance, in English ships are often referred to with feminine pronouns. E.g. you might say "that ship, she's magnificent", but I don't think you would say "that ship, a magnificent female" (unless you were trying to specifically make some kind of comparison relating to femininity (which I suspect is the case here)).

Comment: There is a difference, but in Romance languages, I believe it's quite uncommon to personify something using the opposite sex as the grammatical gender. (But often words have synonyms of the opposite gender, so for example, in French *hope* can be either male or female, depending on whether it's *l'espoir* or *l'espérance*.)

Answer (score 2):

That war is grammatically feminine in Italian probably helps, but the chief element here is that he is personifying war as a *femme fatale*, beautiful and alluring while very dangerous.  This allows him to explain shortly how something so ghastly can also fascinate.

Comment: Is it possible to find some other passages or context in the book to further support this interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Astarte]

However often fought by men, war itself has been personified as feminine longer than writing, [in Mesopotamia as well as among the various Indo-European warbands](https://www.learnreligions.com/war-goddesses-of-the-ancient-world-118520). The Proto-Germanic root of *war* and *guerra* [seems to have been feminine](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/werzan%C4%85) and of course [*guerra*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guerra#Italian) itself is feminine in modern Italian.

[image: Bellona with Janus]

For what it's worth, I know we aren't trying to make Mussolini sound better for the next generation but ***female* is just a cringingly bad/lazy translation here**. *Femmina* should just be *woman* or, if you really wanted to drive home the point about his own vulgarity and the fact he's **purposely** avoiding the more common and respectful *donna*, something base and sexist. His imagery there is doubtless something about how she's really just waiting for a manly man (in tights!) to submit herself to.

Of course that all ended about as well as you'd expect, just from these lines alone.

[image: Mussolini hanging from a petrol station in Milan]

Comment: War is masculine in German [Krieg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/krieg) and neuter in Romanian [război](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C4%83zboi). I think the fact that *guerra/guerre* is feminine is more of an accident than anything else.

Comment: As already sourced, you're wrong but you're certainly welcome to your opinion. _De gustibus_ ...